# Symfony sfDoctrineGuardPlugin custom login query

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, sfdoctrineguard

I use symfony sfDoctrineGuardPlugin to manage authentication for both frontend users and backend users. It's fine, except that I don't want frontend users to be able to login to the backend app. I can setup credentials, but credentials are checked after a user gets authenticated. What I want is to have sigin in form to never validate for a user, that is not in a backend group. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a better solution. sfDoctrineGuard plugin has its own post validator that checks for an optional callable for user retrival.

```
//app.yml
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    retrieve_by_username_callable: sfGuardUser::getForBackend

//sfGuardUser.class.php

  public static function getForBackend($username)
  {
    $query = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery('u')
      ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
      ->leftJoin('g.Permissions p')
      ->where('u.username = ? OR u.email_address = ?', array($username, $username))
      ->addWhere('u.is_active = ?', true)
      ->addWhere('p.name = ?', 'backend');

    return $query->fetchOne();
  }
```

Comment: hi @Dziamid, i'm trying to do the same, but, where should i put this function??

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea: You could try creating a custom post-validator for the login form. Here's a Google result:

http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2008/09/05/call-the-expert-how-to-implement-a-conditional-validator

In this validator, you could check whether the user belongs to the group in question and then throw an error accordingly. The user would not get authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add:

```
  storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: sf_backend
```

at the end of your `backend/config/factories.yml`
By default, symfony shares session cookies, with this solution, symfony separate this cookies.