# Separate frontend and backend users with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: php, plugins, symfony1, sfguard

i'm starting a project adn i'm using symfony, my first time with symfony, really great actually, i already install the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin and everything is ok untill now, why?, because frontend users can login in the backend and vice versa, i dont't want that, so, i start to google, i found [Symfony sfDoctrineGuardPlugin custom login query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735422/symfony-sfdoctrineguardplugin-custom-login-query) here in SO, but i don't know where i should place the function so, i haven't tested it.

As i don't want frontend users can login in the backend, i think i can use credentials, can i?? but, symfony check for users credentials after they are logged, and i don't want tha neither, so, how can i achieve this?, maybe if i could have namespaces in the session, i can check if an admin in the backend namespace and also for frontend users, so they never get fixed, i think.

I don't know really know if sfDoctrineGuardPlugin have some configuration that can manage this situation, exist such a config??

Also, in my backend, i will like to have a page to manage the frontend users, and other for backend users, because frontend users will have a profile and addresses, think this is much easier, but i don't know where to start.

need some help over here

thanks

Comment: Though, you came up with a resonable answer. I suggest you fist analyse if you really need 2 seperate applications. While this may be logical, you will soon find it difficult to reuse code between applications, there is an issue internationalization and testing. I find it much easier to to have 1 application. FYI, Symfony2 doesn't have a concept of 'application' either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days coding, i was able to do it exactly as i wanted, i'm going to share my solution:
I started with an example i found here in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), you can read the post here:
[Symfony sfDoctrineGuardPlugin custom login query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735422/symfony-sfdoctrineguardplugin-custom-login-query)
it gave me an idea and i executed it, so, i create \lib\Util.class.php, with to functions, one for query backend users and another for frontend users

```
static public function retrieveCustomer($username, $isActive = true)
{
    $query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery('u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
    ->leftJoin('g.Permissions p')
    ->where('u.username = ?', $username)
    ->addWhere('u.is_active = ?', $isActive)
    ->addWhere('g.name = ?', 'customers');

    return $query->fetchOne();
}

static public function retrieveAdmin($username, $isActive = true)
{
    $query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery('u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
    ->leftJoin('g.Permissions p')
    ->where('u.username = ?', $username)
    ->addWhere('u.is_active = ?', $isActive)
    ->whereIn('g.name', array('administrators','operators'));

    return $query->fetchOne();
}
```

Now, in the `app.yml` of each app, i override the default query of the plugin

```
#Example for apps/backend/config/app.yml
all:
    sf_guard_plugin:
        retrieve_by_username_callable: Util::retrieveAdmin
```

untill now all was good, but i started to face another problem, so i open a new thread: 
[Overwriting isAuthenticated() in symfony](/questions/5544356/overwriting-isauthenticated-in-symfony) and there i got the final step for my solution, that was setting differents session name for each app, so, in the `factories.yml` of each app:

```
#apps\backend\config\factories.yml
storage:
  class: sfSessionStorage
  param:
    session_name: backend
```

and now all is set, frontend users can not log in in backend app and vice versa.

feel free to comment

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is through credentials, my `backend` applications `security.yml` looks like:

```
all:
  is_secure: on
  credentials: [login_backend]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but credentials are checked after the user is logged in, i don't want that, cuz you can loggin, just can't access this app, in my case, my entire frontend app isn't secure, just certains pages, if i use credentials the user look like is looged in the page that are not secure, and i don't want that